# Prevent from rounding/losing accuracy

Tags: .net, vb.net, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to save some numbers in a decimal variable, e.g. the value could be:

```
Dim someDecimalVar as Decimal = 210.00483839999998
```

The ouput is `210.0048384` but I need the exact value.
Why do the numbers lose accuracy when stored in `decimal`/`double` and how do I prevent this?

Edit: I get the value from an object (trying to make a copy of them) which saves them as double, how is this possible?

Comment: there's a huge difference between `decimal` and `double`; if you have `double` in the mix: there *is* no "exact value" - the term is meaningless; so: is it `decimal` throughout, or not? Can we see example code that shows it losing accuracy between some steps?

Comment: If the number came via a Double, there is a good chance that it really should be 210.0048384 - do you know for a fact that it should be 210.00483839999998? `Dim x = 210.00483839999998D : Console.WriteLine(x)` outputs "210.00483839999998".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without some example code demonstrating the problem to provide context, it's difficult to say for sure what your exact problem is or how to fix it.  However, perhaps this additional information will help you.  You provided the following example:

```
Dim someDecimalVar as Decimal = 210.00483839999998
```

The value `210.00483839999998` is called a literal (i.e. a hard-coded value).  All literals have a specific type, even if the type isn't explicitly stated.  When no type is specified, the compiler infers the type based on the value.  So for instance, it will assume that `1` is an `Integer`, `1.2` is a `Double`, and `"Hello"` is a `String`.  So, in your example code, the number literal is interpreted by the compiler as a `Double` literal, since you didn't specify.  In other words, your code is, more or less, equivalent to the following:

```
Dim someDoubleVar as Double = 210.00483839999998
Dim someDecimalVar as Decimal = someDoubleVar
```

So, how can you specify the type of a literal?  In VB, you do so by adding a [type character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) as a suffix at the end of your literal.  So, if you want to force the compiler to interpret that value as a `Decimal`, you need to add a `D` to the end, like this:

```
Dim someDecimalVar as Decimal = 210.00483839999998D
```

Actually, unless you add the type character to force it to a `Decimal`, the compiler will give you an error saying:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal'.

What that means is, the compiler knows that the conversion from `Double` to `Decimal` may cause the value to lose some precision, so it refuses to do the conversion automatically; it wants you to manually specify that you want to do the conversion so that it knows you're aware of the implications.  It's an extra safety check that the compiler is doing for you just to ensure that you don't accidentally do anything stupid.  The only way to get that to compile without the type character is to turn `Option Strict Off`, so I have to assume that's what you've done.  I would strongly suggest turning `Option Strict On` since it helps to catch these kinds of problems.

Any time you convert between decimals and doubles, the value can lose some precision in the conversion (since they store the value in memory in two different, sometimes incompatible, ways).  So, observe:

```
Dim someDoubleVar As Double = 210.00483839999998R  ' Setting Double to Double retains precision
Dim someDoubleVar2 As Double = 210.00483839999998D  ' Setting Double to Decimal loses precision
Dim someDecimalVar As Decimal = 210.00483839999998D  ' Setting Decimal to Decimal retains precision
Dim someDecimalVar2 As Decimal = 210.00483839999998R  ' Setting Decimal to Double loses precision
```

*Note: the above code will only compile with `Option Strict Off`.  I know... I just said not to do that, but I'm trying to illustrate why your code is doing what it's doing.*

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick play around with the number in your question, and if you convert the double to a decimal explicitly when you assign it to the decimal variable, You get the correct number.

E.G.

```
Dim x As Double = 210.0048383999998
Dim someDecimalVar As Decimal = CDec(x)
```

Comment: I don't get the same result.  When I try that code, the value gets rounded (which is admittedly surprising).  I wonder what the differences are which cause it to work for you.  Option strict, infer, and explicit don't seem to have any effect on it.  I'm compiling via VS 2017, targeting the .NET Framework version 4.6.1.  Maybe you're using Core, Mono, or some other framework?

Comment: Aaaahhh I read the question to mean that the shorter decimal was what was required :-)